# The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established in Gitbash using Windows 10

Tags: github, git-bash, ssh-keys, rsa-key-fingerprint, authenticity

I have created SSH key twice and deleted the previous one and currently using the latest and attached it on Github. Further using GitBash ,I'm Trying to push my changes on github but I'm getting this error -

The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established.

Also some of solutions say that add hosts to known_hosts file, however there is no such file in my laptop OS- Windows 10. Also some say delete the keys which I have already done.
Also this command ls -al ~/.ssh  results in total 10 keys but I don't have more than 1 ssh folder in my laptop.

Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Github updated their host keys: https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

The latest keys are available here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints